# Sparkle.Framework not installing new updates after downloading. Error: An error occurred while extracting the file. Please try again later

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sparkle

I am using Sparkle framework to update my application.

It's checking for updates and downlaoding it but at the time of Installing it's giving an error.

[image]

I am not able to understand why this error is occuring.

I have uploaded my .app file after compressing it to .zip to the server. I do not know why it's not able to extract it.

Please help. I am huge trouble.

> 015-09-08 11:43:30.075 Update[927:19428] Sparkle: ===== Update =====
>   2015-09-08 11:43:30.076 Update[927:19428] Sparkle: Extracting using
>   '/usr/bin/ditto' '-x' '-k' '-' <
>   '/Users/Paxcel/Library/Caches/com.TechHeal.Update/Sparkle/Update
>   1.2/Update.zip' '/Users/Paxcel/Library/Caches/com.TechHeal.Update/Sparkle/Update 1.2'
>   2015-09-08 11:45:06.270 Update[927:19037] Sparkle: Code signature of
>   the new version doesn't match the old version: cdhash
>   H"def198d02dbf94943fc22c626bbb4b36d2248e5a". Please ensure that old
>   and new app is signed using exactly the same certificate. 2015-09-08
>   11:45:06.305 Update[927:19037] Sparkle: host info: {
>       build = 1;
>       format = "bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)";
>       identifier = "com.TechHeal.Update";
>       requirements = "";
>       "signing-time" = "";
>       teamid = "";
>       version = "1.0"; } 2015-09-08 11:45:06.306 Update[927:19037] Sparkle: new info: {
>       build = 2;
>       format = "bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)";
>       identifier = "com.TechHeal.Update";
>       requirements = "";
>       "signing-time" = "";
>       teamid = "";
>       version = "1.2"; } 2015-09-08 11:45:06.308 Update[927:19037] Sparkle: The update archive isn't signed with a DSA key, and the app
>   is signed with a new Code Signing identity that doesn't match code
>   signing of the original app: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-67050 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error
>   -67050.)" UserInfo=0x60000027e880 {SecCSArchitecture=x86_64}. At least one method of signature verification must be valid. The update will be
>   rejected.

Comment: What about the code signing errors - how's your project set up?

Comment: its a dummy application. just a POC

Comment: How's your code signing set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error report is a bit more specific:

...

> *Code signature of the new version doesn't match the old version: cdhash H"def198d02dbf94943fc22c626bbb4b36d2248e5a". Please ensure that old and new app is signed using exactly the same certificate.*

...

> *The update archive isn't signed with a DSA key, and the app is signed with a new Code Signing identity that doesn't match code signing of the original app:*

...

Check your code-signing

Comment: I am not signing my code. its a dummy application. I am just learning Sparkle

Comment: Then sign it. Sparkle requires code-signing to work properly

Comment: ok, I am signing it. Is there anything that I need to add in aapcast after signing the code?

Comment: Please read the Sparkle documentation and the sample code. The description is quite clear